# How to delete user as an admin for other users in Cancan rolify devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'm trying to delete user using regular delete method using users resource in Rails 4 app with  Cancan, Devise and Rolify integration but I'm getting below error now:

```
undefined method `handle_dependency' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasAndBelongsToManyAssociation:0xce991f0>
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Have you got `dependent: :destroy` or similar in your `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship?

Comment: Please post your user model.